# How to see Python errors?

Tags: python, logging

I have a VPS server, on athe provider's data center.
I'm developing something in HTML/PHP that's calling Python code via a shell_exec() call, hence the Python code is based on sys.argv[1] parameter and I cannot test it directly?
Is there a way to see the Python errors, when something doesn't work?

Comment: Log to file in your Python script or capture the output (stdout *and* stderr) from the exec side (PHP?).

Comment: Put `2>&1` at the end of the command that you run with `shell_exec()`. This will include `stderr` in the output.

Comment: My command is $result = shell_exec("/var/www/html/helper.py $param");
How should I change it? Thanks